# Swift iOS App Facebook SDK 4.0 on login/logout methods not executing

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, sdk

So I have been working on a swift iOS app which uses Facebook and its SDK. I have the login button working and it saves information properly however I am unable to run code upon a successful login/logout. The dedicated functions:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    println("User Logged In")
    backButton.hidden = false
    loginText.text = "Thanks for Logging In"
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    println("User Logged Out")
    loginText.text = "Please Login"
    backButton.hidden = true
}
```

do not run at all when the user logs in and out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, if need be I can upload the rest of the code. I am having the problem in two different view controllers not just this one, both of which have their own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign delegate to your FBSDKLoginButton.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 150, 40)
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
}
```

Once user is logged in the following delegate method is called.

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

        println("User Logged In")
    }
```

Once user is logged out the following delegate method is called.

```
func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    println("User Logged Out")
}
```